# I can't figure out the reason of syntax error in my code as shown here

Tags: python

Error is at the line:
`if(number1 or number2 == 'q'):`. It says invalid syntax. Please help me understand this. Thank you.

```
print("Enter two numbers and i will add it for you.")
print("press 'q' to exit at any time\n")
while(1):
    number1 = input("Enter 1st number   ")
    number2 = input("Enter 2nd number   ")

    if(number1 or number2 == 'q'):
        break           

    result = int(number1) + int(number2)
    print("\nThe result of addition of given numbers is " + str(result)+ ".\n")
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback message for the error? I ran your code and it worked for me.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not allowed to access review queues yet.

Comment: @skrrrt - sorry about that. I noticed "top 3%" on your profile but didn't consider point score. You should be there soon.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if(number1 or number2 == 'q'):`

To this

`if(number1 == "q" or number2 == "q"):`

In the first solution, it just returns true since it doesn't check if both of them equals q. You would have to add that extra check for the first variable in order for this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
if(number1) or (number2) == 'q': 
    break
```

above syntax will not cause any error..